# Is there a better way of implementing a list of data?

Tags: .net, database, vb.net

I'm currently using a Database for the data I need, but I don't like having to deal with the database file being seperate from the .exe, and I just want to read data, so I don't need the ability to alter data like you can do using a database.

An example of how I'm using the data (using Pokémon):

```
Dex#       |        Pokémon
----------------------------
1                 Bulbasaur
2                 Ivysaur
3                 Venusaur
         ...
151               Mew
```

So I have a number associated with a name, and I want the user to see/select the name and the program returns the number. Is there a different way to store this data in the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database is used to store complex data structures where transactional integrity is important.  You describe a simple list of two values and imply that this list is immutable and universal.

If that’s the case, the easiest way to “store” the data is as code:

```
Public Class Pokemon 
    Public Property DexNumber as Integer
    Public Property PokemonName as String
End class

Public Function Pokemons As List(Of Pokemon)
    Return New List(Of Pokemon) From {
      New Pokemon With {.DexNumber = 1, .PokemonName=“Bulbasaur”},
      New Pokemon With {.DexNumber = 2, .PokemonName=“Ivysaur”},
      New Pokemon With {.DexNumber = 3, .PokemonName=“Venusaur”}
    }

 End Function
```

Now, it wouldn’t be much harder to store this in a json or xml file and make it easy to add or remove items from the list. With a modicum of extra effort, it could be stored in a SqlServer Express database. Going to a database isn’t really that much harder and will give you a leg up when your structures do start getting more complex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for persistence of static information there are multiple ways to do in .NET. Which one you want is primarily driven by confidentiality, ease of development, testing and change management. Based on your question, it doesn't looks like confidentiality is not a concern. To factor other considerations you can

1. Write everything in static class as readonly properties which is easy to develop and test, but change management is difficult. Change management require deployment though.
2. Use a lightweight NoSQL database like [LiteDB](https://www.litedb.org/). It's available in [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiteDB) and can be added as a dependency to your project and everything will work. No need of separate installation. This doesn't have any schema and you can add as many columns as you want. There is an in memory version of it that ease writing unit tests. Change management shouldn't  require deployment.
3. Store the contents in the appsettings.json (or) app.config in either a Json object format (or) xml format and have it side-by-side to the application. So you get persistence and access easily. Change management shouldn't require deployment.